# Seleccionar filas de una tabla dinámica usando jquery

Tags: jquery

Saludos comunidad tengo la siguiente duda:

Estoy creando una lista en una vista que proviene de otra lista que muestro a traves de una ventana modal, es decir, yo le doy clic a un boton, este me muestra una lista con una serie de elementos, a medida que hago clic, paso los datos a otra lista final que es la que les muestro a continuacion:

```
$("td.clic").on("click",function () {
var valores = "";
var identy = "";
var $objeto = [];

// Obtenemos todos los valores contenidos en los <td> de la fila
// seleccionada

$(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function () {
identy = $(this).attr("id");
valores = $(this).text();
$objeto[identy] = valores;

 });

$("#serviciosclientefinal tbody").append(
"<tr data-precio='"+$objeto.precio+"'>" +
"<td id='id' class='id'>" + $objeto.id + "</td>" +
"<td id='nombreservicio' class='tipo'>" + $objeto.nombreservicio + "</td>" +
"<td id='precio'>" + $objeto.precio + "</td>" +
"<td id='estatus'>"+$objeto.estatus+"</td>"+
"<td id='boton' class='click'>"+ "<input type='button' name='eliminarFila' 
 id='eliminarFila' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' value='Eliminar'>" +" 
</td>"+
"</tr>");
```

Bien el asunto es que yo quiero que al hacer clic en el boton eliminar que esta en la ultima fila de esta tabla dinamica que voy creando, me arroje un mensaje que me diga "hizo clic", es decir busco de capturar el evento clic de cada una de las filas de manera independiente, el objetivo final es poder eliminar el registro de la fila, pero necesito capturar inicialmente el para luego ir haciendo el resto.

Eso se me ocurrio que lo podria hacer asi:

```
$("td.click").on("click",function () {
alert("Se hizo clic");

 }).on("click",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Pero el asunto es que si cargo tres registros en la tabla, cuando hago clic en el primer registro, me muestra el alert 3 veces, si hago clic en el segundo registro me muestra el alert 2 veces y asi sucesivamente, es decir, es como si el alert se repitiera por la cantidad de registros que tengo.

La verdad es que no estoy viendo la metida de pata, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Tú puedes agregar un *listener*  por tipo de elemento, o por clases, o como quieras.

Por ejemplo aquí se agrega un *listener*  a todos los botones que haya en el DOM y luego usas `this` para obtener lo que quieras del elemento que fue clickeado.

```js
$(":button").on("click", function() {
  var btnValor =  $(this).val();
  var btnId    =  $(this).prop('id');
  var btnName  =  $(this).prop('name');
  console.log("Valor: " + btnValor);
  console.log("ID: "    + btnId);
  console.log("Name: "  + btnName);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="btn1Name" id="btn1" type="button" value="btn1">
<input name="btn2Name" id="btn2" type="button" value="btn2">
<input name="btn3Name" id="btn3" type="button" value="btn3">
```

Si quieres que este código funcione solamente con algunos, no con todos los botones del DOM, entonces les asignas una clase que los agrupe y agregas un *listener*  usando como selector esa clase y el elemento `input button`. La clase se puede asignar cuando creas los elementos de forma dinámica, por supuesto.

Por ejemplo aquí tenemos dos *listeners*  diferenciados, según la clase y el tipo de elemento:

```js
/*Escuchando los botones del grupo 1*/
$("input[type='button'].grupo1").on("click", function() {
  var btnValor =  $(this).val();
  var btnId    =  $(this).prop('id');
  var btnName  =  $(this).prop('name');
  console.log("Valor: " + btnValor);
  console.log("ID: "    + btnId);
  console.log("Name: "  + btnName);
});


/*Escuchando los botones del grupo 2*/
$("input[type='button'].grupo2").on("click", function() {
  console.log("Elementos del grupo 2, para ser tratados de otra forma... ");
});
```

```css
.grupo2 {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="grupo1" name="btn1Name" id="btn1" type="button" value="btn1 [grupo1]">
<input class="grupo1" name="btn2Name" id="btn2" type="button" value="btn2 [grupo1]">
<input class="grupo2" name="btn3Name" id="btn3" type="button" value="btn3 [grupo2]">
<input class="grupo2" name="btn4Name" id="btn4" type="button" value="btn4 [grupo2]">
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.